# AES ECB Mode giving different results when using different languages

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to pass an AES encrypted string from a python script into a nodejs script, using ECB mode. The code used is:

To start, I use pycryptodome to encrypt a string into AES

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key = b'ipu9TUv54yv]isFMh5@;t.5w34E2Ry@{'
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
print(cipher.encrypt(b"foobar          "))
```

> This gives me the string `\xb0\x07\x93\xf3\x02\xd0\x87\xa4\xaek\x1bS\xccg\xa4H`.

However, when i try to reverse the effect with Javascript:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')
let key = Buffer.from('ipu9TUv54yv]isFMh5@;t.5w34E2Ry@{');
let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-ecb", key, '');
let result = decipher.update(Buffer.from('\xb0\x07\x93\xf3\x02\xd0\x87\xa4\xaek\x1bS\xccg\xa4H'));
console.log(result.toString())
```

> It gives me a completely different result from the original text: `�k��gR�O`

Is there something that I am missing that is changing the way that it decrypts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two core issues:

On the node side, you're treating the output of Python as if it's a UTF-8 string.  Node will treat it as a UTF-8 string, and the resulting bytes that make up the Buffer are going to be wrong.  Dump it out, you'll see it's a 25 byte buffer, not what you intended.

Once you fix that, you'll find the second issue.  The crypto library expects padding bytes, even if the only block is exactly the block size.  To fix this, always add padding to the plaintext.

So, the encrypt changes to this:

```python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b'ipu9TUv54yv]isFMh5@;t.5w34E2Ry@{'
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
# Don't need to ensure the plain text is exactly block-size anymore
data = b'foobar'
# Pad it, regardless of it's size
length = 16 - (len(data) % 16)
data += bytes([length]) * length

# And encode the encrypted text.  Using hex here, it's easy, though
# often base64 is used
print(cipher.encrypt(data).hex())
```

And decoding in Node:

```node
var crypto = require('crypto')
let key = Buffer.from('ipu9TUv54yv]isFMh5@;t.5w34E2Ry@{');
let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-ecb", key, '');
// Using the hex encoding, let Buffer decode it
let result = decipher.update(Buffer.from('bf8242c6046ad5cb47e733dca4d487f1', 'hex'));
// Make sure to give decipher a chance to operate on the final block
result += decipher.final();
console.log(result.toString())
```

This outputs `foobar` as expected.

Comment: ya could you please show me how to decrypt this data in python ?

Comment: please share some code it will help me :)